# Can the python interpreter listen to SIGKILL or SIGTERM signals and get killed while having a deadlock?

Tags: python, linux, docker, deadlock

I have a web application that is having random deadlocks

I know which feature is causing the problem, but i do not know the exact cause yet within that feature, So i thought that i should try and kill the process and restart it. I do this on a regular basis for daily (automated) backups, data wiping, maintainance, etc... but i have never done it in a deadlock situation in which the whole program stops and it is probably ignoring all sorts of input and signals

I have not been able to test anything, since it has been hard to debug locally in the first place: I have not been able to trigger the deadlock by reproducing the situations described by my users when they were using the feature

Comment: Programs don't have to listen for signals to get killed by them. They *can't* listen for SIGKILL at all.

Comment: @user2357112 but then how do I terminate a deadlocked program?

Comment: kill(1) should still work; if not, `kill -9` will reliably and immediately terminate it, at the cost of not giving it an opportunity to clean itself up.  `docker stop` does both of these things.

Comment: @DavidMaze `docker stop` will surely kill it but unfortunately i am hosting this in a PaaS platform, so i don't have any control over any docker commands: the platform is in full control of that. I will try the `kill -9` though, and see if it works

Comment: In Kubernetes, `kubectl delete pod` uses the same Unix-signal-based mechanism, and it's likely your PaaS environment has something similar.

Comment: @DavidMaze i don't have access to the pods or the cluster: It's a bring-your-github-repo-and-we-will-mount-it-for-you platform, but thanks for the tip anyways